# localhost redirected you too many times. ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Tags: php, session, session-cookies

I keep getting this error since last night for my index.php page only. i have cleared all my cookies but still i cant access index.php on local host. i have looked at other solutions but couldn't find an answer.

I think it is to do with my index.php code which redirects me to the same page to login. but i am new to web development i am not sure how to tackle the issue. below i have provided snippet of my index.php and login.php. any help is highly appreciated.

login.php

```html
<?php
session_start();
// Change this to your connection info.
$DB_HOST = 'localhost';
$DB_USER = 'root';
$DB_PASS = '';
$DB_NAME = 'ecom';
// Try and connect using the info above.
$con = mysqli_connect($DB_HOST, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS, $DB_NAME);
if ( mysqli_connect_errno() ) {
 // If there is an error with the connection, stop the script and display the error.
 die ('Failed to connect to MySQL: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
}

// Now we check if the data from the login form was submitted, isset() will check if the data exists.
if ( !isset($_POST['username'], $_POST['password']) ) {
 // Could not get the data that should have been sent.
 die ('Please fill both the username and password field!');
}


if ($stmt = $con->prepare('SELECT id, password FROM users WHERE username = ?')) {
 // Bind parameters (s = string, i = int, b = blob, etc), in our case the username is a string so we use "s"
 $stmt->bind_param('s', $_POST['username']);
 $stmt->execute();
 // Store the result so we can check if the account exists in the database.
 $stmt->store_result();
}
 
 if ($stmt->num_rows > 0) {
 $stmt->bind_result($id, $password);
 $stmt->fetch();
 // Account exists, now we verify the password.
 // password_hash function in is used in registration file to store the hashed passwords.
 if (password_verify($_POST['password'], $password)) {
  // Verification success! User has loggedin!
  // Create sessions so we know the user is logged in, they basically act like cookies but remember the data on the server.
  session_regenerate_id();
  $_SESSION['loggedin'] = TRUE;
  $_SESSION['name'] = $_POST['username'];
  $_SESSION['id'] = $id;
  /*echo 'Welcome ' . $_SESSION['name'] . '!';*/
  header('Location: index.php');
 } else {
  echo 'Incorrect password!';
 }
} else {
 echo 'Incorrect username!';
}
$stmt->close();


?>
```

index.php

```html
<?php

// We need to use sessions, so you should always start sessions using the below code.
session_start();

// If the user is not logged in redirect to the login page...
if (!isset($_SESSION['loggedin'])) {
 header('Location:index.php');
 exit();
}
?>

<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
<!-- Required meta tags -->
<title>City Outlet</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link href="css/style.css?10" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"> 
<!-- awesome-font CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>

 
<!--========== Top bar Area ============-->
  
<header class="topbar">
 <nav>   &nbsp;  &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
    <a style="color:white; font-size:18" href="logout.php"><i class="fa fa-sign-out style="font-size:24px; color:white;""></i>Logout</a>
    &nbsp;  &nbsp; 
    <button href="" class="btn login btn-default d-inline-flex" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#loginModal" ><i class="fa fa-sign-in"  style="font-size:24px" value="login" onClick="showModal()" ></i> Login</button>
   
  &nbsp;  &nbsp; 
   <button href="" class="btn login btn-default d-inline-flex" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#signupModal"><i class="fa fa-user"  style="font-size:24px" ></i> Sign Up</button>
  &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; 
  </nav>
    
  <p style="color:white; font-weight:bold; text-align:right; line-height:-10px; margin-top: 7px;"> Welcome: <strong style="color:red; font-weight:bold;"><?=$_SESSION['name']?></strong>! &nbsp;<img src="images/ava.png" style=width:25px; height="25px;"> </p>

</header>

<!-- Login Modal  -->
<div class="loginbox" id="loginModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel"
    aria-hidden="true"> <img class="avatar" src="images/redavatar.png">
  <h1>Sign in</h1>
  <form action="login.php" method="post">
    <p>Username</p>
    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Enter username" required>
    <p>Password</p>
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter password" required>
    <input type="submit" name="submit"  value="submit">
    &nbsp;  &nbsp; 
    <a href="signup.php">Not a member?</a> <br>
   <br>
  </form>
</div>

<!----- Sign up Modal  ----->

<div class="container">
 <h1 class="text-white bg-dark text-center"></h1>
 
 <div class="modal" id="signupModal">
 <div class="modal-dialog ">
  <div class= "modal-content">
  
   
   <div class="modal-header">
    <h3 >Sign Up</h3>
       <button style="color:red" type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" > &times;</button>
   </div>
   <div class="modal-body">
   <form action="signup.php" method="post" >
    <div class="form-group">
     <label><i class="fa fa-user fa-2x"></i>  First name:
     </label>
     <input type="text"  name="username" class="form-control" placeholder="your name"  required>
    </div>
    
    <div class="form-group">
     <label><i class="fa fa-lock fa-2x"></i>  Password:
     </label>
     <input type="password"  name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="choose password" required>
    </div>
    
    <div class="form-group">
     <label><i class="fa fa-envelope fa-2x"></i>  Email:
     </label>
     <input type="text"  name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Your email"  required>
    </div>
    <input type="submit">
    </form>
   
   </div>
   
  </div>
  
  
  
  </div>
 
 
 </div>
 
 
 </div>
  
<!----- Sign up Modal  ----->
  
 
<!--========== End Top bar Area ============-->

<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-md navbar-light ">
  <div class="container-fluid"> <a class="navbar-brand " href="index.php"> <img src="images/citylogo.png" alt=""> </a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler third-button darken-3" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <div class="animated-icon3"><span></span><span></span><span></span></div>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active"> <a class="nav-link" href="index.php">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a> </li>
        <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">Services</a> </li>
        <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="shop.php">Shop</a> </li>
        <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="booking.php">Booking</a> </li>
        <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="gallery.html">Gallery</a> </li>
        <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="contact.html">Contact</a> </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="searchbar" action="/action_page.php" style="margin:auto;max-width:300px">
   <button type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Search.." name="search2">
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<!-- Optional JavaScript --> 
<!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS --> 
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script> 
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js"></script> 
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 

 
<script>
    
   function showModal()
{
  document.getElementById("loginModal").style.display = 'block';
}
   </script>
 
 <script>
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('id01');

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
</script>
 
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: In your index, you re-direct to your index - causing an infinite loop.

Comment: You are redirecting to the same file, that is what's causing the infinite loop.

Comment: `header('Location:index.php');` to `header('Location:other_page.php');` on index.php page seems solve your problem

Comment: thanks for your comments guys . the reason i re-direct to index.php is to allow me login when i am not logged in , as i have my login and signup form on index.php for login purposes.

Answer (score 0):

On index.php
This part of the code.

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['loggedin'])) {
    header('Location:index.php'); // redirecting to same page.
    exit();
}
```

You are redirecting to the same page if the user is not log in, thats why you have the infinite redirects... You must redirect to other page like a login page.

Comment: thanks for your answer,   i have  login modal form on my index.php which allows the user to go on that page to login. that is why i redirect the user to that page when not logged in.

Comment: yes I saw it, but you have your redirect on the top page, the user is not going to see the modal form.. you logic have to be updated. example have a new pae for login or do not display the info on index.php only the form if the user is not login.

Comment: when you say do not display the info on index.php , are you talking about the info that shows wether the user is logged in or logged out?

Comment: if you have some info or navigation for the login user don't display it and tell the user to login.

Comment: when i redirect to login.php it just shows " Please fill both the username and password field!"  , do i need to add a html file containing the same login-form that i have on index.php to allow the user to login.  please help

Comment: you will need to create a full html page with the username and password field and the proper post url on the form to authenticate the user. your login php is for authenticating the values, to to show the login form.

Comment: thank you so much for your advice and assistant.  i have created a new html page  login.html and direct  the user to it when the user is not logged in .Now i can login from login.html page and the  user info shows on index.php.  There is one thing : i cant access my index.php page unless i logged in. Can you please advice what i should do or change to make make my index.php the main page to be visible when logged out . and login whenever you want from the login.html ??  many thanks for your help

Comment: That was my second comment, you need to remove the redirect and instead show information for the login user or show information for the guest user based if the user is login or not .

Comment: I am already showing the information for the user in my index.php when logged in.  but if i remove the redirect   header('Location: login.html');  , can you please tell me what  do i replace it with.

Comment: i tried this code but  it didn't work .      `   <?php
session_start();

// If the user is not logged in redirect to the login page...
if (!isset($_SESSION['loggedin'])) {
<p style="color:white; font-weight:bold; text-align:right; line-height:-10px; margin-top: 7px;"> Welcome: <strong style="color:red; font-weight:bold;"><?=$_SESSION['name']?></strong>! &nbsp;<img src="images/ava.png" style=width:25px; height="25px;"> </p>
}
?> `